# Python simple type checking decorator

Tags: python, python-3.x, meta-programming, type-safety

I'd like to know your opinions on this minimal type-checking decorator  (with `@` annotations) to make type checking of a method while debugging like :

```py
def typecheck(*tuples, **kwtuples):
    def decorator(func):
        def function_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):

            #print('tuples : ' , tuples)
            #print('kwtuples : ' , kwtuples)            
            #print('args : ' , args)            
            #print('kwargs : ' , kwargs)

            for index, tup in enumerate(tuples):
                arg = args[index]
                if not isinstance(arg, tup):
                    raise ValueError('in ' + str(func.__name__) + ' : wrong argument on position ,' + str(index) + ' :'  + str(arg) + ' must be of type :' + str(tup) + 'but is' + str(type(arg)) )

            for key, tup in kwtuples.items():
                arg = kwargs[key]
                if not isinstance(args[index], tup):
                    raise ValueError('in ' + str(func.__name__) + ' : wrong argument ' + str(key) + ' :'  + str(arg) + ' must be of type :' + str(tup) + 'but is' + str(type(arg)) )




        #print("arguments: ", *args, **kwargs)
            func(*args, **kwargs)
        return function_wrapper
    return decorator


@typecheck(str,(str, float))    
def foo2(x,y):
    print("Hi, foo has been called with ",str(x) ,y)

foo2('2',3.4)
```

The benefit of it is :

- Custom and detailed description about the wrong argument
- Later, you can extend this for custom validation like some item is in some range or structural inspection of an argument.
- Easy to write, apply and delete after testing (so it won't consume cpu time)

Comment: Have you considered somehow taking advantage of [type hints, introduced in Python 3.5](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/typing.html)? (And if not, why?)

Comment: In addition to @200_success other than using `typing` and mypy/pyre/pyright/pytype for _static type enforcement_, you can also use something like [pytypes](https://pypi.org/project/pytypes/) for run-time type enforcement.

Comment: those stuff do not custom value checking or structural  checking, dont they? also i want it to be easy removed after testing

Answer (score 5):

To amplify @200_success’s comment:

Python 3.5 introduces [type hints](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html).  Eg)

```
>>> def foo2(x:str, y:float) -> None:
...    print(f"Hi, foo has been called with {x} {y}")
... 
>>> foo2("2", 3.4)
Hi, foo has been called with 2 3.4
>>>
```

These type hints (the `x:str`, and `y:float`) are not used by the standard Python interpreter, but they are recorded during the parsing of the code, so they are available to the program.

```
>>> foo2.__annotations__
{'return': None, 'x': <class 'str'>, 'y': <class 'float'>}
>>>
```

Directly accessing the `foo2.__annotations__` is not that interesting, but accessing `func.__annotations__` in the `@typecheck` decorator means you don’t have to provide the argument types to the decorator; the decorator can inspect the argument types directly.  Thus you could decorate the function with simply `@typecheck`, instead of `@typecheck(str, float)`.

For a variant `str` or `float` type argument, you could use the `typing` module to define your own `STR_OR_FLOAT = TypeVar("STR_OR_FLOAT", str, float)` type (or a better name if you have one), which you could decorate the argument with.

As a bonus, using type hints to provide argument type checking information — even for your do-it-yourself via a function decorator type check system — also gives you the following benefits:

- IDE type hints, as you are writing code
- Can be understood by standard documentation generators
- Only consumes CPU time during parsing of the code; does not affect execution speed